# Kubernetes Ingress with external Reverse Proxy

Tags: kubernetes, apache2, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress, kubernetes-dashboard

I'm trying to make the kubernetes dashboard externally accessible.
For this i installed nginx-ingress as ingress controller in my kubernetes cluster which is accessible on port 32012 on the kubernetes node IP.
Now i want to make it accessible via a domain like k8s.xxx.xx. For that I'd create a TLS certificate from Lets Encrypt to secure the whole thing via HTTPS.
Now we have a Apache2 reverse proxy which handles the requests going to k8s.xxx.xx and proxies them to port 32012, but here I'm getting a error from nginx-ingress:
**The plain HTTP request was sent to HTTPS port**

The connection chain is:
User -> https://k8s.xxx.xx/ > Apache2 reverse proxy redirecting to port 32012 on kubernetes node and handles Lets Encrypt certificate > ingress controller > kubernetes-dashboard pod.

My kubernetes ingress component looks like the following:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: kubernetes-dashboard-ingress
  namespace: kubernetes-dashboard
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: "HTTPS"
spec:
  rules:
  - host: k8s.xxx.xx
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: kubernetes-dashboard
            port:
              number: 443
```

Comment: Based off the connection chain, it seems like apache could be reverse proxying over http and not https, if you dont have access to apache you could try altering the ingress shown to accept http and see if that works. Maybe include your apache configuration? Also ensure that NodePort 32012, is for the https listener on your service.

Comment: It's like the annotation `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: "https"` doesn't work. Are you sure it's applied?